# WSIT, policy settings for client side in Netbeans and Metro JAX-WS RI

Tags: netbeans, jax-ws, wsit

The published wsdl of the web-service we work with has a Policy tag.

But after we create a client using wsimport and Netbeans, it would not allow to edit any attributes of WSIT settings. *In Apache CXF you can supply the attributes via API.* As far as we see, in case of Metro and Netbeans it needs an xml file with the policy attributes set. 
Documentation says that those attributes can be edited via Web service client' settings and xml automatically generated. But in our case no WSIT (Security) tab is accessible.

[image: No Security tab]

Here, documentation presents how the properties should look like. http://metro.java.net/nonav/1.2/guide/Configuring_Security_Using_NetBeans_IDE.html#gfrds
(Security tab)

Is there any easy way to provide the client with options as message signing, keystore and trustore (as published service required)?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this issue?